Facing issue printing Hindi text to Pdf Using Java iText
The wrong spelling is in the image
I am using Java iText to generate report from josn data , I am facing issue with Hindi spelling. The google Font I am using is NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf
//This is the function
private void addTextToPdf(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String text, float x, float y, int pageNumber, int fontSize, PdfFont font) throws IOException {
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNumber);
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

    // Convert text to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
    String lowerText = text.toLowerCase();

    // Determine the color based on the text value
    DeviceRgb rectangleColor = null;
    String marathiText = text; // Default to the original text

    // Draw the rectangle with the determined color
    if (rectangleColor != null) {
        drawRectangle(pdfDocument, x-2f, y - 2.8f, 85.5f, 12f, rectangleColor);
    }

    // Add the Marathi text to the PDF
    canvas.beginText()
          .setFontAndSize(font, fontSize)
          .setColor(ColorConstants.BLACK, true)
          .moveText(x, y)
          .showText(marathiText)
          .endText();
}


"वर्धा" is the string I pass and the one in image is printed , However on coping from pdf "वर्धा" is copied

To properly render Hindi, you need to use com.itextpdf.layout.Canvas from layout module, instead of com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas from kernel module. Because layout is responsible for advanced work with PDF (in our case script layouting).
Also, to be able to apply Hindi, you need to use pdfCalligraph product from iText, see https://itextpdf.com/products/pdfcalligraph.
With these 2 moments your code of addTextToPdf should looks like:
//This is the function
private void addTextToPdf(PdfDocument pdfDocument, String text, float x, float y, int pageNumber, int fontSize, PdfFont font) throws IOException {
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNumber);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(page, pdfDocument.getDefaultPageSize());

    // Convert text to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
    String lowerText = text.toLowerCase();

    // Determine the color based on the text value
    DeviceRgb rectangleColor = null;
    String marathiText = text; // Default to the original text

    // Draw the rectangle with the determined color
    if (rectangleColor != null) {
        drawRectangle(pdfDocument, x-2f, y - 2.8f, 85.5f, 12f, rectangleColor);
    }

    // Add the Marathi text to the PDF
    canvas.showTextAligned(
            new Paragraph(text)
                    .setFont(font)
                    .setFontSize(fontSize)
                    .setFontColor(ColorConstants.BLACK),
            x, y, TextAlignment.LEFT);
    canvas.close();
}

